# Why loop formed after click on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have styled file input:

```
<div class="fakeFileContainer">
 <div class="fakeFile">Dołącz brief</div>
 <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
</div>
```

for this part of code I have some line of js:

```
var fileInput = $('#contact #file')

fileInput.change(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $('#contact form .fakeFile').text($this.val());
})

$('#contact form .fakeFileContainer').on('click', function () {
    fileInput.click(); //looping here
}).show();
```

After click on `.fakeFileContainer` I've got this error msg in console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

It's caused by loop, but I don't know why this loop formed here. Can comeone explain me reason of this situation?

---

*P.S. Please excuse any spelling or grammatical mistakes, English isn't my first language*

Comment: Both are right bellow you just keep clicking a click to a click! What do you want your click to do?

Comment: You should never need two IDs in one selector: `$('#contact #file')`.  IDs should be unique, so you only need `$('#file')`.

Comment: @JeffB Ok I will remember that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The triggered click event bubbles up, and you catch it right on the parent element to trigger the next click - creating an infinite loop. To prevent this, you can either

- `stopPropagation` of click events on the input
- do not trigger clicks if the handled event was issued on the input (by checking the `srcElement`)
- or put the click handler on the `.fakeFile` div instead of the surrounding container.

Comment: Or you can add a selector to the `.on()`: $('#contact form .fakeFileContainer').on('click', '.fakeFile', function (e) {})

Comment: @jmoerdyk: That's just the same solution, only with event delegation which is unecessary here.

Comment: just listing another possibility to your list, didn't say it was the best option :P

Answer (score 6):

Your clicks on `fileInput` are handled by that function too (because the even bubbles up to the container). So the code says: "when clicked, trigger another click event". That second click event causes the same question to be asked again, and the answer is, again, to fire another click event. Thus, an infinite loop.

Comment: Now I don't know wich answer accept. You both explain me my problem, but @Bergi also show me solution so don't be angry if I accept him answer :)

Comment: I'm glad you accepted his answer, since he offered a solution while I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The click event on the `fileInput` is causing the event to bubble up to the `.fakeFileContainer`. Change your click event to not bubble:

```
$('#contact form .fakeFileContainer').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    fileInput.click();
}).show();
```

Some sort of combination of that should keep it from looping up to the `.fakeFileContainer`.

Comment: With jQuery events, you should use the `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up.

Comment: When I add `e` as argument I've got `<error>` in console and it cause showing page break.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $("#fakeFileContainer").on('click', function (e) {

        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log(e);

        $("#file")[0].click();

    });
```

chnage class "fakeFileContainer" to id "fakeFileContainer" and put $("#file")[0].click(); it's work for me .